# How to make container environment variables available to process.env?

Tags: docker, vue.js, kubernetes, azure-aks

I am deploying my VueJS application to AKS. Now when the app is deployed, I do see the environment variables in the container, but when I try to use them using process.env in my code, I only see the env variables from the .env file.

I am inserting my env variables in my deployment.yaml like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.app.name }}-deployment
  labels:
    app-name: {{ .Values.app.name }}
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app-name: {{ .Values.app.name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app-name: {{ .Values.app.name }}
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: {{ .Values.app.serviceAccountName }}
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: {{ .Values.app.image }}
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          {{- if $.Values.env }}
          env:
            {{- range $key, $value := $.Values.env }}
            - name: {{ $key }}
              value: {{ $value | quote }}
            {{- end }}
          {{- end }}
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
```

My environment variables reside in a values file.

Does anyone know if I have to add something else here or somewhere else?

Comment: `process.env` object works only in dev mode. **once you build and deploy your client side app (vue, react etc), all the env variables get replaces by there actual value**. any variable inject in the container later on won't get read by the compiled code. client code runs in the browser and the browser doesn't `process.env` object.